# Keycloak postgres throwsDatasource '<default>': FATAL: role "keycloak" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, keycloak

I am using podman for starting a keycloak with a postgres in a pod. I am using GitLab for that.
The postgres which is created does not have the role keyclock. I used the official Dockerfile from https://www.keycloak.org/server/containers with modifications as bellow:

```
    ENV KC_FEATURES=token-exchange
    ENV KC_DB=postgres
    RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build
    
    FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
    COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/lib/quarkus/ /opt/keycloak/lib/quarkus/
    WORKDIR /opt/keycloak
    # for demonstration purposes only, please make sure to use proper certificates in production instead
    RUN keytool -genkeypair -storepass password -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -dname "CN=server" -alias server -ext "SAN:c=DNS:localhost,IP:127.0.0.1" -keystore conf/server.keystore
    ENV KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
    ENV KC_DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/keycloak
    # change these values to point to a running postgres instance
    ENV KC_DB_USERNAME=${DB_USERNAME}
    ENV KC_DB_PASSWORD=${DB_PASS}
    ENV KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=${KC_ADMIN_PASS}
    ENV KC_HOSTNAME=https://localhost:8443
    EXPOSE 8443
    ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh", "start"]

and the yml file is:

    stages:
  - build

build_pod:
  tags:
    - auth-runner
  stage: build
  script:
    - podman pod rm -i -f user-authentification
    - podman pod create --name user-authentification -p 9175:8443
  only:
    - main
build_db:
  image: postgres:14
  tags:
    - auth-runner
  stage: build
  script:
    - podman run -dt --name postgres --pod user-authentification -v ~/postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:z
      -e POSTGRES_DB="$KEYCLOAK_DB_NAME" -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD="$KEYCLOAK_DB_PASS" postgres
  only:
    - main
build_keycloak:
  tags:
    - auth-runner
  stage: build
  script:
    - podman build --build-arg DB_USERNAME=postgres --build-arg DB_PASS=$KEYCLOAK_DB_PASS --build-arg KC_ADMIN_PASS=$KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASS -t sdx-keycloak .
    - podman run -dt --name sdx-keyclaok-container --pod user-authentification sdx-keycloak
  only:
      - main
```

postgres error:

```
2022-02-22 21:08:45.800 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.2 (Debian 14.2-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
2022-02-22 21:08:45.801 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2022-02-22 21:08:45.801 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2022-02-22 21:08:45.803 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2022-02-22 21:08:45.808 UTC [26] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-02-22 21:08:40 UTC
2022-02-22 21:08:45.815 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2022-02-22 21:08:54.605 UTC [33] FATAL:  role "keycloak" does not exist
2022-02-22 21:08:57.867 UTC [34] FATAL:  role "keycloak" does not exist
```

Keycloak error:

```
    2022-02-23 08:03:49,005 INFO  [org.keycloak.common.Profile] (main) Preview feature enabled: token_exchange
2022-02-23 08:03:49,025 INFO  [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.hostname.DefaultHostnameProvider] (main) Hostname settings: FrontEnd: https://localhost:8443, Strict 

HTTPS: true, Path: <request>, Strict BackChannel: false, Admin: <request>
2022-02-23 08:03:49,561 WARN  [io.agroal.pool] (agroal-11) Datasource '<default>': FATAL: role "keycloak" does not exist
2022-02-23 08:03:49,562 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator] (JPA Startup Thread: keycloak-default) HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: role "keycloak" does not exist
```

Answer (score 1):

found the answer in https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/453#issuecomment-393939412

needed to delete the volume.